# Installing helm tiller on running K8s cluster failed to fetch stable helm repository url with error 403 forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am managing my k8s cluster using terraform and has tiller version 0.10.4,

Now I made some changes in my terraform file. so when I run **terraform init** I am getting following error.

*error initializing local helm home: Looks like "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml : 403 Forbidden*

So I change the stable url in my terraform file, and now it looks something like

```
data "helm_repository" "stable" {
  name = "stable"
  url = "https://charts.helm.sh/stable"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "kubeconfig.yaml"
}

provider "helm" {
  install_tiller = true
  version = "0.10.4"
  service_account = "tiller"
  namespace = "kube-system"

  kubernetes {
    config_path = "kubeconfig.yaml"
  }
}
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: did you try with `v0.10.6` instead of `version = "0.10.4"` ? https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/issues/649

Comment: Adiii's suggestion of upgrading provider version seems like it should fix it? Fwiw though, after that I was getting 403s at tf apply stage for any stable charts, the only fix I found was to override the `repository` argument on each [helm_release resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/0.10.6/docs/resources/release#repository)

Answer (score 1):

The old Google based Chart storage system has been decommissioned. But also Helm 2 is no longer supported at all and Helm 3 does not use Tiller. You can find a static mirror of the old charts repo on Github if you go poking, but you need to upgrade to Helm 3 anyway so just do that instead.

Comment: Instead of upgrading to new version, is there any other way to set stable url in provider helm ?

Comment: Try `helm repo remove stable && helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable` or something like that. But again, both Helm 2 and the community charts are beyond their end-of-life period, there are known security issues in many community charts _that will never be fixed in those versions_.

Comment: Where should I run this command, as this is terraform file.

Comment: On whatever server or laptop this is running on.

Comment: So on my server tiller is alreay installed in kube-system namespace, so I ran (helm init --client-only --stable-repo-url https://charts.helm.sh/stable) but after that also same error

Comment: Tiller does not talk to the charts repo at any point, this is a purely local error because you have a repo set up on your workstation/server pointed at the old Google hosting which has been taken down.